# Magento Installation Fatal error

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, e-commerce, magento2

I am beginner in the magento field and trying to install magento on localhost.
I am using XAMPP server 7.2.1 and magento 2.2.2
The Configuration get all set but when I hit localhost/magento in browser it shows me fatel error like

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager::get($name, ?array $options = NULL) must be compatible with Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager::get($name, $options = Array, $usePeeringServiceManagers = true) in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\PluginManager.php on line 211
```

Comment: I'm not sure if Magento 2.2.2 supports PHP 7.2.*. On the official docs, there are only 7.1 and some versions of the 7.0 branche are marked as supported.

Comment: so any suggetion for my further installation?

Comment: Please, try install magento on a server with PHP 7.1.*

Comment: check this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Answer (score 2):

As reported [here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2/Fatal-Error-Installing-on-XXamp/m-p/83571#M3441) and [here](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-cache/issues/142) the latest version of XAMPP (the PHP version packed with it) is not compatible with latest Magento versions.

> Magento 2 dosen't support the version of php that the latest xampp has
>   packed with it. The problem should be fixed if you download an older
>   version of xampp that has a php version packed compatible with magento 2.

So, as already suggested, the solution is that either you downgrade your PHP version or the complete XAMPP package.